# jQuery nth-child confusion

Tags: jquery-selectors

On this page:
https://weargustin.com/store?filter=all

Why is the first element of this selector:

```
$('div.funded.product:nth-child(3n)')
```

The second element of

```
$('div.funded.product')
```

?!

Comment: Try `(3n+3)` instead. (http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Comment: I think you mean `(3n+1)`, but that doesn't explain why `3n` doesn't work. I'm baffled, `(3n)` should be equivalent to 0,3,6,9 etc, with 0 being no match.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is make sure it really is selecting the second child, and that when you examine the DOM in your browser there aren't any other child nodes. I'm pretty sure (but not certain) that nth-child counts anonymous text nodes. If it does, empty space could throw off your count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that nth-child loops over all children and tests them against the selector. It does not use the selector and then loop over those that match. So as PSL mentioned, the other items you have which are siblings are throwing the whole thing off.

Here's an example fiddle to break it down: http://jsfiddle.net/Ga5Jq/

```
<div>
        <p>test</p>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
</div>


$(function() {
    alert($("div span:nth-child(3n)").html());
});
```

The above code alerts `2` because the second span is really the third child of `div` matching the selector, `span`.

Comment: Yup change it to  `alert($("div span:nth-of-type(3n)").html());` and see it alerting the right one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to select every 3rd of that type so you should try using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` since there are many other siblings to start with other than `div.funded.product`. For instance you have the div `.product.funding` also coming in as the child of the same parent.

```
$('div.funded.product:nth-of-type(3n+1)')
```

See [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)